# How to JOIN efficiently 2 tables that both have DATETIME values

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, join, inner-join

I have a MYSQL database with 2 tables A and B that both have a StartDateTime and EndDateTime column (which are DATETIME variables).

However table B gets more entries (of smaller duration) than A. For now table A has 11000 rows while table B has 84000 rows.

This result on a very slow query when I try to join the 2 tables (which share an index).

Is there a way to link those 2 tables with a query that doesn't take forever?

Here are the first 20 rows of Table A datetimes:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| StartDateTime       | endDateTime         |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2013-10-04 13:48:11 | 2013-10-04 14:10:23 |
| 2013-10-04 13:48:19 | 2013-10-04 13:48:29 |
| 2013-10-04 13:48:28 | 2013-10-04 14:10:06 |
| 2013-10-04 13:48:41 | 2013-10-04 13:48:42 |
| 2013-10-04 13:48:49 | 2013-10-04 14:10:23 |
| 2013-10-04 13:49:19 | 2013-10-04 14:10:23 |
| 2013-10-04 13:52:40 | 2013-10-04 13:52:40 |
| 2013-10-04 13:52:46 | 2013-10-04 13:52:46 |
| 2013-10-04 13:53:16 | 2013-10-04 13:53:26 |
| 2013-10-04 13:54:16 | 2013-10-04 13:54:26 |
| 2013-10-04 13:54:26 | 2013-10-04 13:54:26 |
| 2013-10-04 13:54:56 | 2013-10-04 13:54:56 |
| 2013-10-04 13:55:21 | 2013-10-04 13:55:51 |
| 2013-10-04 13:56:37 | 2013-10-04 13:56:37 |
| 2013-10-04 13:56:51 | 2013-10-04 13:56:51 |
| 2013-10-04 13:56:56 | 2013-10-04 13:56:57 |
| 2013-10-04 13:57:21 | 2013-10-04 13:57:21 |
| 2013-10-04 13:57:27 | 2013-10-04 13:57:27 |
| 2013-10-04 13:58:58 | 2013-10-04 13:59:18 |
| 2013-10-04 13:59:08 | 2013-10-04 14:10:06 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

And here the first 20 rows of table B datetimes:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| StartDateTime       | endDateTime         |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2013-10-04 13:48:13 | 2013-10-04 13:48:14 |
| 2013-10-04 13:48:14 | 2013-10-04 13:48:15 |
| 2013-10-04 13:48:17 | 2013-10-04 13:48:18 |
| 2013-10-04 13:48:26 | 2013-10-04 13:48:27 |
| 2013-10-04 13:48:30 | 2013-10-04 13:48:42 |
| 2013-10-04 13:48:33 | 2013-10-04 13:48:33 |
| 2013-10-04 13:48:34 | 2013-10-04 13:48:35 |
| 2013-10-04 13:48:36 | 2013-10-04 13:48:38 |
| 2013-10-04 13:48:38 | 2013-10-04 13:48:39 |
| 2013-10-04 13:48:40 | 2013-10-04 13:48:41 |
| 2013-10-04 13:48:47 | 2013-10-04 13:48:48 |
| 2013-10-04 13:48:48 | 2013-10-04 13:48:50 |
| 2013-10-04 13:48:49 | 2013-10-04 13:48:50 |
| 2013-10-04 13:48:51 | 2013-10-04 13:48:53 |
| 2013-10-04 13:48:55 | 2013-10-04 13:48:58 |
| 2013-10-04 13:49:03 | 2013-10-04 13:49:06 |
| 2013-10-04 13:49:13 | 2013-10-04 13:49:15 |
| 2013-10-04 13:49:21 | 2013-10-04 13:49:22 |
| 2013-10-04 13:49:24 | 2013-10-04 13:49:25 |
| 2013-10-04 13:49:26 | 2013-10-04 13:49:27 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

EDIT: The 2 views I'm doing the query on and the query. The query works perfectly except that it takes 5 min 48 to give the result.

**VIEW 1:**

`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DurationOfUseByApp AS 
SELECT fkDeviceUserKey, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) AS duration, 
ExecutableName 
FROM ProcessInfo 
INNER JOIN ExecutableInfo 
ON ProcessInfo.fkExecutableId = ExecutableInfo.idExecutableId;`

**VIEW 2:**

`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW InputUseEvents AS
SELECT fkDeviceUserKey, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) AS duration, 
DeviceType, EventCount1, EventCount2, EventCount3, EventCount4
FROM InputUse 
INNER JOIN InputDeviceName 
ON InputDeviceName.idInputDeviceName = InputUse.fkInputDeviceName 
ORDER BY StartDateTime;`

**Query :**

`SELECT '2013-01-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', DurationOfUseByApp.StartDateTime)/15) * 15 minute AS TimeInterval, 
SUM(IF(DeviceType = 4, EventCount1+EventCount2+EventCount3+EventCount4, 0)) AS nbOfTrackpadEvent, 
SUM(IF(DeviceType = 3, EventCount1+EventCount2+EventCount3+EventCount4, 0)) AS nbOfMouseEvent, 
SUM(IF(DeviceType = 5, EventCount1+EventCount2+EventCount3+EventCount4, 0)) AS nbOfHIDEvent, 
IF(ExecutableName = 'chrome', DurationOfUseByApp.duration/60, 0) AS chrome 
FROM InputUseEvents INNER JOIN DurationOfUseByApp USING (fkDeviceUserKey) 
WHERE DurationOfUseByApp.StartDateTime >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND DurationOfUseByApp.StartDateTime <= '2014-01-01 23:59:59' AND DurationOfUseByApp.StartDateTime <= InputUseEvents.StartDateTime AND DurationOfUseByApp.EndDateTime >= InputUseEvents.EndDateTime 
GROUP BY TimeInterval 
HAVING chrome > 0`

Thanks,
Zohm

Comment: You'll have to post the query you tried. We can't fix what we can't see.

Comment: The queries I do are working, just slow (a few minutes), even a basic one like: `SELECT A.StartDateTime, B.StartDateTime FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.index = B.index;`

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to write a query to link those tables together efficiently despite the very different number of rows. So I could use that method for any query between the 2 tables in the future.

Comment: Is it the query taking the time, or bringing back 11000 or 84000 rows? You simple query above will bring back every matching row in that index but with nothing to narrow it down. Hence likely the index on table 1 is ignored as it is narrowing nothing down.

Comment: Yep I know. That's why I'm looking for a way to group the rows in the second table to bring them to the same number of rows that the first table (here 84k to 11k). Once I have this I could just use aggregate function such as sum/ count / avg on other variables. For now I'm dividing the time by 15min intervals and then using aggregates functions on other variables, which works fine. But it takes almost 6min, which is way to much. And the table will only grow bigger, so I need to improve that.

Comment: Can you post the table declares and the actual full query that is causing problems?

Comment: It's in the edit part of the post.

Comment: The use of views is probably resulting in the indexes not being used in your main query.

Comment: Well I thought the view could be the problem. But when I tried the same query using the original tables it didn't change anything.

Comment: Few comments. The order clause on the 2nd view is not going to be helpful for these queries. Each view is bringing back all the records without taking any notice of narrowing down the rows based on date (hence likely no index used). The 2nd view is calculating a value (duration) which is not used (and the first produces a value for duration which your other query then performs another calcuation on - may as well combine them). Probably a few more ways to improve things easily. However to give more details I would need the table declares (at least).

Comment: The duration is not used in the query but is used in other ones that are also using the view. The duration is calculated in both tables but not on the same StartDateTime and EndDateTime since each tables has its own variables for times which does not share the same entries. For the linking of the table, is there a way to link them using the date as here but by also taking advantage of the indexes?

Comment: With the durations, might be best to set up new vies which do not calculate them for queries that do not use the duration. However to get the queries to perform well you would probably be best off avoiding using view, and recode the query to just do the joins between the tables directly. Can you post the table declares?